# how to profile memory usage in dart apps?

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, dart, google-chrome-devtools

I have [this](http://0xor1.net/purity_memory_profile_test/index.html) test app for looking at memory profiles of my dart app. When you click the "new client" button in the top left it will simulate a new client browsing to the host. The host generates a new app session which in this case is a simple app which can create or delete `Massive` objects. The massive objects live on the Host and the blue squares are the client side representations of the `Massive` objects. I expect that if I create a bunch of `Massive` objects and then delete them all, taking heap snapshots along the way, I should see the memory usage rise as the `Massive` object count increases, and then decrease as the `Massive` objects are eventually garbage collected, a remote garbage collection is run every 5 seconds which frees the actual `Massive` object on the Host side so it should then be free for the actual VM garbage collector to clear away.

I have been trying to use the Chrome dev tools to see the heap allocation as I create multiple clients and dispose of the `MassiveView`s on them. but I don't see anything at all, creating a new `Massive` object I see a spike in memory allocation but after the object should be freed I don't see any sign of memory usage going down, but I don't know whether I'm using the dev tools wrong or if my framework is just buggy. Is it possible to see a continual feed of memory allocation in Chrome dev tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal memory view that is used for JavaScript applications does not work with Dart.

You can use the "Heap Profile" option in the Dart Observatory. It is a build in feature of the DartVM. If you are using Dartium you can access it via the DevTools, there is a tab that is called "Observatory".

But it also work in the standalone DartVM. You have a command line option to activate it, or if you are using the Dart Editor, you can activate it in the launch configuration of you app.

The Dart Observatory is quite new since the dev channel versions of 1.4 and is not [completely finished](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18358), you might have to upgrade. There is no documentation available yet.